# XPath: handling invalid second parameter of contains() function

Tags: xpath

I have kind of invalid xpath expression where second parameter is not a string:

```
//ng-messages/span[contains(., fieldName)]
```

This expression still returns some of span's. I'm curious how xpath handles this invalid second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate in expression `span[contains(., fieldName)]` checks if the current `span` element contains the value of `string(fieldName)`, where `fieldName` is child of the `span`.

The predicate will evaluates to `true` if `fieldName` exists whatever its content, because `fieldName` is part of the `span`. And it is also evaluates to `true` when the `span` doesn't have child `fieldName`, because `string(fieldName)` will then returns an empty string and the expression `contains('whatever', '')` is always evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

See [XPath 1.0, §3.2 Function Calls](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Function-Calls):

> A FunctionCall expression is evaluated by using the FunctionName to identify a function in the expression evaluation context function library, evaluating each of the Arguments, **converting each argument to the type required by the function**, and finally calling the function, passing it the converted arguments.
>
> **An argument is converted to type string as if by calling the `string` function.** (...)

[`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) is defined like this:

> **Function**: boolean contains(string, string)
>
> The contains function returns true if the first argument string contains the second argument string, and otherwise returns false.

And finally, the [`string()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) function has all cases defined depending on the input: node-set, number, boolean. If it's something else:

> An object of a type other than the four basic types is converted to a string in a way that is dependent on that type.

At first sight, I don't know how your XPath engine will convert  `fieldName`.